# TinyMCE Blazor Server - Intermittent Loading Issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tinymce, blazor-server-side

as the title suggests I'm having an issue with the Blazor version of the TinyMCE editor. I know it's something that I'm doing / not doing because it's working in one part of the app but in another part of the app im getting intermittent loading issues.

Where I am seeing the issue is on an @page, I have the following code (*there are two editors on the page, just to test I have removed one just in case*)

```
@if (Q.Type == QType.Text)
{
    <TinyMCE.Blazor.Editor @ref="QuestionRef" CloudChannel="6" Conf="editorConf" Disable="@(!IsAssignedTo || IsComplete)" Id="question" @bind-Value="Response.TextResponse" Field="() => Response.TextResponse" ApiKey="" />
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        /* removed code for clarity */
        await LoadResponse();
    }
}

private async Task LoadResponse()
{
    /* removed code for clarity */
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The problem I see is that when the page first loads it **sometimes** doesnt load the TinyMCE editor correctly and just shows a TextArea with no content (even though the Response.TextResponse has a value)

I also see the following errors in the console output in both Chrome and Edge
here are 2 messages in the console output

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at tinymce.min.js:9:26875
at HTMLLinkElement.h (tinymce.min.js:9:26961)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerWidth')
at jA. (theme.min.js:9:279034)
at hA.dispatch (tinymce.min.js:9:372724)
at jA.dispatch (tinymce.min.js:9:373978)
at Array. (tinymce.min.js:9:400272)
at Ne (tinymce.min.js:9:5303)
at Object.KA (tinymce.min.js:9:400182)
at ia.executeHandlers (tinymce.min.js:9:52234)
at i (tinymce.min.js:9:50072)
```

Any help or advice anyone can offer would be very much appreciate as I've been banging my head against a brick wall with this one.

Comment: It seems like moving the code to load the model for the page into
`protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()` seems to have helped and now the control is working as expected. Well for now anyway, im keeping my eye on it.

Comment: Nope, still having the issue, although its reduced now.
I am now going to try the following to see if this helps, im not at my laptop at the moment but will try it and see if it does later.
`protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(tab.IsActive)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("tinymce.init", new object[] { });
    }
}`